# Nuget activate "Include Prerelease" via config file

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

Visual Studio 2017 offers the option to include prereleases of NuGet package via the GUI, like shown below:

[image]

Does anybody knows if it is possible to do this via `NuGet.config` or via `csproj` file?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anybody knows if it is possible to do this via NuGet.config or via csproj file?

I am afraid you could not activate the option `Include Prerelease` via `NuGet.config` or via `csproj` file.

Because this is a unique feature of Visual Studio instance, we could not use the configuration file of NuGet package management or the project file to change the Visual Studio configuration.

Besides, this is a long-term saved setting, if you check this checkbox, it will not unchecked until you change it next time.

What is more, NuGet team also provide us options `-IncludePrerelease` and `-prerelease`, so that we could use the pre-release package without NuGet package management UI.

Check more info from [Installing and updating pre-release packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/prerelease-packages#installing-and-updating-pre-release-packages).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You mean to have this option set per default when opening the packagemanager ? not possible unfortunately